# Persona song appearing in Catherine?

Tags: catherine, persona-4

During Otakon this year I was jamming to various game and anime tracks on my bass in the halls.  Saturday night a Persona cosplayer (can't remember if he was from 3 or 4) came up to me and asked me to play his theme.  Not having played any of the Persona games before, I was completely at a loss for what he was requesting until I remembered that I had been playing the ending to Catherine earlier that day.  I started playing it again, and he's like, "Yeah, that's the one!"

Unfortunately, in all the excitement of the rest of the weekend I forgot which character he was, and while researching this has produced some enjoyable hours spent on YouTube, I haven't found anything that I would have mistaken for Catherine's ending.

Can anyone pin down the character in question?

**EDIT**
Here's the song I was playing:

Comment: This song doesn't appear in any Persona game that I've ever played, so I'm not sure what that person could have been talking about. (Not to mention that characters in the Persona games, other than Arena, generally aren't given "theme songs" per se.)

Comment: Maybe it is a similar soundtrack? The artist in charge of this is also in charge of the sound for Persona 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [Catherine soundtrack](https://www.discogs.com/Shoji-Meguro-CATHERINE-Original-Soundtrack/release/11445187) doesn't have any crossover with the [Persona 3](https://www.discogs.com/Shoji-Meguro-Persona3-Original-Soundtrack/release/8606510) or [Persona 4](https://www.discogs.com/Shoji-Meguro-Persona4-Original-Soundtrack/release/6681558) soundtracks.

They are indeed very similar, being from the same composer, [Shoji Meguro](https://www.discogs.com/artist/359317-Shoji-Meguro?layout=sm&page=1).